# How to include spaces in addTextChangeListener()?

Tags: java, android

How do I include spaces in the `EditText` in `onTextChanged()`? Like SQL query `SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%a %';`

In my code, upon typing the keyword + space it will vanish the result. for example, I want to find "King Pin" then I typed into `EditText` "King P" but the method doesn't generate the result.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, title);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        myFragment.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of tricky to check for spaces in `addTextChangeListener`. Generally people try to avoid the space issue by using **trim()** method and also  put code in `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` method for better results. Try using

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     myFragment.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString()).trim();
}
```

Comment: charSequence is invalid comand in afterTextChanged, sorry i'm new

Comment: how about there is an ideal number on the listview for example 
1. King pin
2. King Jo
3. King Lee

i gonna search for king lee. when i type "King L" it's still vanishing the result. but if i include "3. King L" it will generate.. how can you fix this?

Comment: try using Regex. that will help you acheiving it

Comment: if i do that, is it still capable for searching only the numbers?

Comment: @Jezreelovers Regex is big module, you can check this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html